# When printing a memory address of a variable using printf, why do %x and %p return different yet similar values?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the memory address of a variable (specifically argc). I am using printf and I know that %x returns an unsigned hexadecimal integer and %p returns a pointer address. My simple code is below for reference

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("argc: addr=%x addrp=%p val=%x\n",&argc,&argc,argc);
  return 0;
}
```

Ran like so: ./a.out this is

It outputs: argc: addr=af5144cc addrp=0x7ffcaf5144cc val=3

I see that the %x returns what is the address of a byte, correct? Since it has 8 digits or bits?

However, %p returns what is the same byte with more info before it. What is the "0x7ffc" part and what does it mean? Is it part of the memory address or does it point out some type of information? I know the 0x part means it is a hexadecimal number. Is %x or %p the true memory address? Thanks!

Comment: Printing pointers with `%x` is *undefined behavior*. Printing non-`void` pointers with anything is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `%x` prints an `unsigned int`, which on most modern plaforms, is 32-bit.  `%p` prints a platform-specific pointer value.  Some platforms are 32-bit, some are 64-bit, there may be other sizes too.

Comment: Your `unsigned` has 32 bits, but the pointers have 64 bits, so the `%x` is truncating the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%x` prints an `unsigned int`, which on most modern platforms, is 32-bits.

`%p` prints a platform-specific pointer value.
Some platforms are 32-bit, some are 64-bit (there may be other sizes too)

`sizeof(unsigned int)` is often equal to `sizeof(void*)`, but it is not guaranteed at all, and it is common to see 32-bit `unsigned int` with 64-bit `void*`.

As a result, `%x` and `%p` print different widths.

Comment: Without mentioning any of these is *undefined behavior* this answer is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks. So %p is returning a larger value because I have a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Size correlation is irrelevant.  It is simple UB because "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

The code is invoking *undefined behavior*. The `fprintf` specification from the [C Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) is stating (the emphasis is mine):

For `%x`

> o,u,x,X
>    -- The **unsigned int** argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal 
>      (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd;

And for `%p`:

> p
>     The argument shall be a **pointer to void**. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

And then [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9):

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, **the behavior is undefined**.

You are feeding both specifiers it with a non-void pointers, which are definitely not the correct type for the conversion specification.

**Update**

As suggested by @chux the fully compliant call will look as following:

```
printf("argc: addr=%x addrp=%p val=%x\n", 
    (unsigned)(uintptr_t)(void*) &argc, (void*)&argc, (unsigned)argc);
```

Comment: Suggest adding a compliant `printf()`.  Maybe `printf("argc: addr=%x addrp=%p val=%x\n", (unsigned) &argc, (void*)&argc, (unsigned)argc);`?

Comment: @chux I think `(unsigned) &argc` is UB as well?

Comment: `(unsigned) &argc` is OK "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type." §6.3.2.3 6 unless "If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined."  So maybe `(unsigned) (uintptr_t) (void*)&argc`

Comment: @chux Ah, OK. I was reading these two sentences as if there is an exception that some pointers cannot be represented as an integer type. Now I see I misread this.

Answer (score 2):

Because pointers are not integers.

Pointers are *pointers*.  The right way to printf a pointer is using `%p`.

You might think you know that pointers are just integers.  (Back in the day, pointers *were* just integers.)  If you know what you're doing, you can still probably get away with treating pointers as integers, but you have to know what you're doing.

For example, you have to know how big your pointers actually are.  They might not be the same size as plain `int`, especially if you're on a so-called 64-bit platform.

So if `%x` doesn't work, you might be able to get away with `%lx`, or `%llx`.  But, most of the time, it's easier (and more portable) to just use `%p`.